# Opinions on this operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

this is more of an ask for opinions, rather than a specific difficulty that I'm having with my codebase.  Take the following simple example:-

```
class Ref
{
    public:
        Ref(char* s, size_t l) : _s(s), _l(l) {}
    private:
        char* _s;
        size_t _l;
};

std::stringstream ss;

char a[256];
ss >> Ref(a, sizeof(a));   // <-------- here is the discussion line

friend std::stringstream& operator>>(std::stringstream& ss, Ref& r)
{
    // perform some functionality
}
```

Now when using Visual Studio the above compiles fine...  It seems to figure out that when I use the operator >>, that because I have an override that takes a reference that I mean to pass the created object as a reference.  However, when using gcc, it throws a wobbly.  It complains that I have no operator overload for the operation.

Technically, I think gcc is correct because I am creating the object and essentially passing the object to the operator and not a reference to the object.  I'm just wondering why the Microsoft compiler would allow this, or why gcc can't figure out that I'm intending to pass it by reference?  In the above case, where the Ref object is fairly trivial, passing by reference or the object itself matters little, but if Ref was something more complex and heavy, then it probably could end up being an issue.

So, I'm asking people what they think about the above...  and give some recommendations.  Obviously you could construct Ref and pass by reference, or change the operator overload to take the object rather than a reference, but it's really a more about this difference between Visual Studio and gcc and what your opinion is.

Comment: Which versions of the compilers are you using?

Comment: And neither compiler complains about the `friend` outside of a class definition?  You surprise me.

Comment: The above code is just an example...  I'm using friend inside the class definition, but that wasn't my point.  It's about the binding of non-const temporaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc is correct, you need `const Ref& r` for it to compile.
`Ref(a, sizeof(a))` creates a temporary and this can only be bound to constant lvalue references.
The reason Microsoft compiles the code, is due to its non-conforming evil extension which allows non-const lvalue references to bind to temporaries. Compile with `/W4` to get a warning about it.

Answer (score 2):

MSVC has got an extension that allows binding a reference to non-const to a temporary object. This is non-standard behaviour. Gcc doesn't have such an extension and rightfuly complains.

```
ss >> Ref(a, sizeof(a));
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//    temporary

friend std::stringstream& operator>>(std::stringstream& ss, Ref& r)
//                                  reference to non-const  ^^^^^^
```

> Obviously you could construct Ref and pass by reference, or change the operator overload to take the object rather than a reference.

The latter isn't really an option if you need to use `Ref` object after the call to `operator>>`. The former is the way to go.

Comment: oh is this a remenant of older msvc compilers or is it intentionally there?

Comment: I don't use MSVC, but AFAIK it's intentional. I don't know what were they smoking... :)

Comment: This particular language extension is an unfortunate heritage from earlier VC versions that had to be kept in there for compatibility reasons. On Warning level 4 (`/W4`) this will generate a warning though and it can be disabled (along with [other proprietary extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx)) using the [`/Za`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) switch.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are attempting to bind a temporary to a non-const lvalue reference, which is not allowed in standard C++. Visual studio has an extension that makes your code compile, whereas GCC sticks to the standard.

You can bypass the problem entirely by not passing a temporary:

```
Ref r(a, sizeof(a)); 
ss >> r;
```

Comment: I did already suggest that you could construct Ref and pass by reference...  it's really more a question about people's opinions and this rather "worrying" little difference.

Comment: @TheWelder opinions about what? I don't see anything to opine about.

Comment: Opinions about the fact that the Microsoft compiler allows this behaviour and gcc does not.  I know why it happens, it wasn't something I really thought about until I was porting some code to gcc.

Comment: @TheWelder So is not meant for soliciting opinions (in fact, it is a reason for question closing), but for what it is worth, I think language extensions are bad in general, because they lead to non-portable code, and this one in particular is a bit nonsensical, because it allows you to modify a temporary, which doesn't make much sense. But this second argument is a weaker one: the language is full of things that do not make complete sense.